# Using Insertion Sort in a single linked list and deleting nodes

Tags: sorting, nodes, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm trying to make a code where 10 numbers are given (unsorted) and I have to sort them using insertion sort and delete the nodes. So for example if the 10 numbers are

> 50 20 30 10 100 90 80 70 60 40

The result sould be

> 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
>   50 is deleted
>   10 20 30 40 60 70 80 90 100
>   20 is deleted
>   10 30 40 60 70 80 90 100
>   30 is deleted
>   ...
>   40

So the nodes are deleted in the order they were given in the first place. 
void PrintNode(), callInsertNode(),callDeleteNode() were given by the way(with other ones that are not posted here. I only posted the necessary ones), and I tried to complete the void InsertNode(int v) and void DeleteNode(int v).

```
 class Node{
    public:
       int value;
       Node *next;
}; 
class LinkedList{ //Singly Linked List
    public:
        LinkedList(){
        head=NULL;
    private:
        Node *head;
        int *x;
        int n;
 }
 void InsertNode(int v){
    cout<<v<<" is inserted"<<endl;

    Node* cur=head;
    if(cur== NULL || cur->next == NULL) {
       return;
    }

    Node *t1 = cur->next;
    while(t1 != NULL) {
        int sec_data = t1->value;
        int found = 0;
        Node *t2 = cur;
        while(t2 != t1) {
            if(t2->value > t1->value && found == 0) {
                sec_data = t2->value;
                t2->value = t1->value;
                found = 1;
                t2 = t2->next;
            } else {
                if(found == 1) {
                    int temp = sec_data;
                    sec_data = t2->value;
                    t2->value= temp;
              }
                t2 = t2->next;
          }
       }
       t2->value = sec_data;
       t1 = t1->next;
 }     

   void PrintNode(){
      Node *cur=head; 
      while(cur!=0){
          cout<<cur->value<<" "; 
          cur=cur->next; 
      } 
      cout<<endl;
   }
   void CallInsertNode(){
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)      
         InsertNode(x[i]);   
   }

   void CallDeleteNode(){
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<n; i++){  
          DeleteNode(x[i]); 
          this->PrintNode(); 
      }
   }
   void DeleteNode(int v){
      cout<<v<<" is deleted."<<endl;

      Node *cur=head;
      Node *previous = head; 
      Node *delNode=cur;

      while(cur!=NULL) 
          if(cur->value == v)
         {
           previous->next = delNode->next; 
           delete delNode;
           return;
         }
         previous = cur; 
         cur=cur->next;
     }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to know if the codes I wrote are right!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks correct to me. Just do some testing with some random data in case I am missing / overlooking something. But otherwise (going through the code and dry running) it looks ok.